# how to get which view is open from app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to produce some function when user comes out of app

I found applicationDidEnterBackground function in appDelegate file but I can't reach view controller which is open right now therefore I can't reach needed function
I can't use instantiateViewController function because it creates a new one, but I need the info stored in the view which is already open

Is there any way to call function of already open instance of view controller???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't very clear. Could you add some code to show what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sometimes have a similar requirement, so I made a `UIViewController` extension with a static method to return the "top" viewController.  It looks like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    static func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
        let viewController = viewController ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController, !navigationController.viewControllers.isEmpty {
            return self.topViewController(navigationController.viewControllers.last)
        } else if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController,
            let selectedController = tabBarController.selectedViewController {
            return self.topViewController(selectedController)
        } else if let presentedController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
            return self.topViewController(presentedController)
        }
        return viewController
    }

}
```

This allows you to get a reference to the viewController being displayed by calling `let top: UIViewController? = UIViewController.topViewController()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some way
I am pretty sure it is real stupid way, but it works in my situation because I exactly know which View Controller I need

1st step: create a variable in appDelegate class

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var myViewController:ExampleViewController?
```

2nd step: in myViewController class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    delegate. myViewController = self       
}
```

And now I can call any function of myViewController class from AppDelegate class

variable of view controller is optional so I unwrap it with "?" sign and don't have problems when app didEnterBackground from other view controllers